# Is an emulsion of dish soap and vegetable oil stable?

Tags: stability, surfactants

If I fill a glass jar with water, vegetable oil, and dish soap, then mix it until the oil is completely emulsified, will the mixture stay emulsified indefinitely?

Assuming the dish soap and oil are chemically stable and do not degrade or otherwise change over time, if I left the jar on a shelf for years, would it remain emulsified? If I heated the jar up (but not enough to boil or decompose anything), or froze it, or shook it, or put it in a centrifuge, would it stay emulsified?

Comment: I'm gonna go with yes.

Comment: No, it won't remain stable.  You cannot have any arbitrary ratio for a stable emulsion. Recall the types of emulsions oil in water vs. water in oil. If you notice, dishwashing soap has dozens of other additives to stabilize the dishwashing liquid and prevent phase separation. Nobody can make a prediction what will happen after boiling heating.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could add some context. What is the background of this query?

Comment: Mostly I am curious. There was a comment chain on reddit about washing oily things with soap and someone asked if the oil would become unemulsified. The context seemed to be about pouring grease/oil down the drain being bad vs cleaning up oily dishes being good. That made me wonder, under what conditions if any (applicable to drains and sewers) would emulsified cooking oil become not emulsified.

Comment: Ethan, Oil/grease solidification in sewers is a completely different case. Sewage water does not contain enough detergency to keep oil separated and also think of other junk (very complex biology and chemistry there). Also think of precipitation of fatty acids/soaps via calcium and magnesium ions. I lived in a very cold country and it was prohibited to discard cooking oil down the sink.

Comment: "Sewage water does not contain enough detergency to keep oil separated" What does this mean? If I am washing a bunch of oily dishes (and dump the wash water down the sink), does the oil become not separated? "Also think of precipitation of fatty acids/soaps via calcium and magnesium ions." TIL

Comment: Your dishwashing solution plus oil/fats from dirty dishes dishes sitting in warm water will remain emulsified as long as the oil-soap ratio is appropriate, eventually your sink water will meet the sewage water, which is mostly water and very low detegerent conc. The oil will eventually separate out/oxidize and the detergent will eventually be decomposed by bacteria. UK sewers have tons and tons of solid fat/oil/grease cakes. :-( That is nasty. Youtube has documentaries on it.